# How do I cut and separate part of a cylinder shape?

Tags: modeling

I created this image, then added a plane to indicate where to cut.

[image]

I had tried Loop Cut, but that changed the angle of the top section.

How do I cut at the location of the plane?  Later I plan to delete the plane and separate the top portion from the bottom portion

---

--- Allen Simpson procedure:

I select the plane:

[image]

I hold shift and select the cylinder:

[image]

I have to sweep the mouse over the entire cylinder to select it.

I do not see the Plane with a dark orange outline and the Cylinder with a bright orange outline.

---

--- Chris procedure: After numerous attempts, did not work for me.

---

--- With Loop Cut, I can place loop at the correct location and angle.

What command cuts?

---

Comment: Ever tried the knife tool?

Comment: I tried the knife, but did not get a straight line.  I was unable to get out of the knife mode ... right click and left click did not stop the knife mode.  Selecting other icons did not work either.

Comment: There used to be a fast way to do this with the plane itself using booltool.  This function appears to be broken right now.

Answer (score 3):

We can still do this fairly easily you just need to follow a couple of additional steps.  Start with the setup in your question and enable the Bool Tool addon from *Edit* -> *Preferences*.

[image]

First select the Plane, and then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the Cylinder, so that the Plane has a dark orange outline and the Cylinder has the bright orange outline.  In other words the Cylinder is your *Active Selection* and is the object that will be operated upon.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> or use the <kbd>F3</kbd> function search to look for *Bool Tool* -> *Difference*.  (Two operations will be listed, select the top one.)  The result should be:

[image]

Now use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate **both** the Cylinder and Plane.

Select the second Plane that you just created (Plane.001), press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into edit mode.  With all four of the plane's vertices selected, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and select *Flip* to flip the plane's normal.

With this step completed, you have reversed the effect of the *Difference Boolean* on the second Cylinder and should be left with two separated pieces.

[image]

You can select both Cylinders and apply the *Boolean Modifiers* if you desire.

[image]

Afterwards you can delete the planes as they are not useful anymore.

[image]

(Bool Tool used to do all of this automatically with the *Slice* operation, but since... I think the introduction of the *Exact Solver* this function is broken.)

Comment: I've added comments to the original post ... not resolved.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/modes.html You were in edit mode instead of object mode.  My post isn't that detailed

Answer (score 0):

1. select your cylinder in object mode, than press TAB to enter edit mode

[image]

2. choose viewpoint -> left

[image]

[image]

3. tap on Knife [image]
4. click one time with your knife positioned on the upper right so you get this:

[image]

5. Tap on C so that in the status bar appear C: cut through (ON)

[image]

6. now move your mouse left of the cylinder and up or down as you need like this and click:

[image]

7. Press RETURN

[image]

8. click here to get back to selection mode :

[image]

now move your view so that you see the cylinder like this

[image]

and change to vertex select mode by clicking here:

[image]

9. now select two vertices of the top circle ...

[image]

and choose select edge loops:

[image]

[image]

now deselect that single vertex by holding CTRL and clicking on it:

[image]

then press x and choose vertices:

[image]