# How do I initiate a Loop Cut?

Tags: modeling

I am attempting to cut a cylinder with Loop Cut.

[image]

How do I cut and separate the top from the bottom?

I have tried the knife.  Cannot get a straight line.  Hitting Enter does get out of the key mode.  But it marked only half of the cylinder. How do I mark the entire cylinder? (It appears LoopCut does that.) And how do I get a straight line?

---

Loop Cut works correctly. It places a loop at a location and angle on an item.

Is there a single command that cuts? We would end up with two items.

Then I take one of the two items and join it with a different item.

Are there simple commands to perform cut and join?

Comment: You already got answer in your last question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247244/how-do-i-cut-and-separate-part-of-a-cylinder-shape

Comment: Similar question, but a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the knife tool with K, press C to cut through, cut, keep the new edge loop selected and press V to separate. Then, as John Eason says, put your mouse over one of the 2 parts and press L to select, and P to separate as a new object if necessary.

Comment: When I enter K nothing happens.  Ditto for entering C and V.  Where should the mouse be to initiate?

Comment: Are you in Edit mode? Please share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: In the Edit mode ... see initial post.  When I enter K, a knife appears.  Nothing else changes from initial post.

Comment: you need to left click and drag, C to cut through, then Enter to validate the cut

Comment: The key is Enter.  Thanks.  It marked only half.  How do I mark the entire cylinder?  (It appears LoopCut does that.)  And how do I get a straight line?

Comment: @ttom As moonboots said, C to cut through.

Comment: if you mean orthogonal, it's A (since Blender 3, previous versions use others shortcuts)

Comment: If you've successfully used the knife cut and you then want to separate the top and bottom, select the loop that you've just cut by ALT-clicking on it and hit 'V' to rip the top and bottom parts. Then in face mode hover over a face in the top part and hit 'L' to select it. You can then either hit 'P' Separate Selection if you want it to be a new object or just drag it around or delete it if required.

Comment: I have not successfully cut using the knife.  Only half of the cylinder is marked with a knife.   How do I mark the entire cylinder ... with a straight line?

Comment: @ttom Z to cut through until 2.9, then it is C since 3.0, maybe it's your problem? Also C to cut orthogonally became A since 3.0

Comment: If you look in the bottom status bar while the knife tool is activated it shows the hotkeys you can use and the status of them at the time.

Comment: When I rotate the cylinder, only half is marked. The backside is not marked.  And it is a crooked line.

Comment: So none of the shortcuts i gave worked? It should be Z or C. If not please share your object

Comment: The file, "Cylinder.blend", can be found at https://Temp.FoxPing.com